# Why array brackets are not being printed in the console?

Tags: javascript

I have a code similar to this one, I'm trying to output an array to the console, but it's required for me (in my case) that the brackets of the array " [] " show up in the console

```js
const x = (...c) => {
    const array = c.find((value) => {
        return true
    })
    let error = new Error()
    error = Object.assign(error, { message: `You have committed a crime! ${array}` })
    throw error.message
}
console.log(x([1, 2, 3]))
```

Output:

[image: output]

- **I'm using nodeJS**.

Comment: The template literal converts the array to a string.

Comment: @terrymorse, no, try to console.log(value); after the find() method, it's indeed returning an array

Comment: If you need cosmetic brackets, just wrap the placeholder in the template literal with brackets: `[${array}]`.

Comment: Or use `${JSON.stringify(array)}`

Comment: @Teemu, reply for " If you need cosmetic brackets ", no, the code above is just a sample of what I'm actually making, I'm making a validator module that validates if the input isFunction, or isArray, or isObject or isString ...etc so this output will change from one type to another

Comment: In that case there are a couple of working answers below. In general, you should ask for what you need, don't simplify too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify` (if you want no brackets without values between, use str.replace as below):

```js
const x = (...c) => {
    const array = c.find((value) => {
        return true
    })
    let error = new Error()
    error = Object.assign(error, { message: `You have committed a crime! ` + JSON.stringify(array).replace("{}", "").replace("[]", "") })
    throw error.message
}
console.log(x([]))
```

Comment: No, that's not what I intended, this is printing {}. I want it to print [] only in case there was an array

Comment: @Ekmek edited my answer, is that what you intended ?

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but could you please explain it? because if you tried to convert my entire code and make it print an object instead of an array, it will print {} normally without the need of using JSON.stringify(), so the damn is only on arrays?

Comment: seems so @Ekmek, but the explaining someone else must do :/

Comment: @Ekmek edited my answer again, when the array is empty, no brackets will be shown !

Comment: @Ekmek The `${}` in a string literal converts the contents to a string. If you do `${myObject}`, you will get "[object Object]", and so forth.

Comment: Thanks, @terrymorse, yes, this is because how toString() method works behind the scenes

Answer (score 1):

`[1,2,3].toString() === '1,2,3'`. If you want to represent the array with brackets, use `${JSON.stringify(array)}`.

Comment: Good answer, now I can see the idea obviously, thanks to Zac Anger and frederic